# Need help to speed up my code in Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, http-post

I have written an Excel macro where i am sending multiple HTTP post JSON requests and saving the response in Excel.
Each Excel row corresponds to one JSON request where each column is one JSON element, I read the Excel row by row using for loop create JSONs at run time, do a POST request and save the request and response back in another Excel tab.

It takes approx 5 seconds to complete one flow which includes capturing data from Excel row, create JSON at run time, saving JSON in another Excel tab, send the POST request and get response, save the response in Excel tab.

I ran it on debug mode and observed that it takes maximum time at `http.send` step.

Is there a way to reduce the time of POST request and speed up this code?

Below is the part of code I am using for this.

```
Tag1 = ws.Range("E3:E" & rowCount).Value
Tag2 = ws.Range("F3:F" & rowCount).Value
Tag3 = ws.Range("G3:G" & rowCount).Value
Tag4 = ws.Range("H3:H" & rowCount).Value

 For i = 1 To UBound(Caps, 1)
    If runFlag(i, 1) = "Run" Then
        RequestXML = "{""Caps"":""" & Caps(i, 1) & """,""pros"":""" & pros(i, 1) & """,""lookAheadTag"":""" & NumberOfTags(i, 1) & """,""Tag"":[" & Tag1(i, 1) & "," & Tag2(i, 1) & "," & Tag3(i, 1) & "," & Tag4(i, 1) & "]}"

        Worksheets("URLsAndJSON").Cells(i + 2, 1) = RequestXML

        'xml object
        Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
        http.SetOption(2) = 13056
        'open the connection
        http.Open "POST", URL, False
        http.SetRequestHeader "content-type", "application/json"

        'Send the input file
        http.Send RequestXML

        response = http.ResponseText

        'save the response
        Worksheets("URLsAndJSON").Cells(i + 2, 2) = response
        Worksheets("URLsAndJSON").Cells(i + 2, 3) = http.Status
        Worksheets("URLsAndJSON").Cells(i + 2, 4) = http.statusText
    End If
Next
```

I have read that VB does not support multithreading but there are workarounds but I want to keep it simple hence not implementing that for now. That will be my second option. For now I want to optimize above code to increase speed.

Comment: Writing to the sheet repeatedly is what is slowing down your macro. Create an array and use it to store all the values for that iteration, then write them all to the sheet at once.

Comment: Your problem is likely 95% external to your code  - you cannot speed up the processing on the server (unless you own it, or the API supports making batched requests)

Comment: You might also use (before and after your code block, respectively): 'Application.ScreenUpdating = False'                            
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True'